# Template debugging in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that is:

```
template <class identifier,class registeredObject>
class FxPairRegistry : public FxRegistry<pair<identifier,registeredObject> >
{
 public:
  registeredObject GetEntry(identifier, FxBool assertValue = true);
  void RegisterInOrder(const pair<identifier,registeredObject> &ob);

  typedef typename std::vector<pair<identifier,registeredObject> >::iterator iter;
};
```

I then have:

```
template <class identifier,class registeredObject>
registeredObject FxPairRegistry<identifier,registeredObject>::GetEntry(identifier id, FxBool 
assertValue)
{
 for (iterator iter = mRegistryList.begin(); iter != mRegistryList.end(); iter++)
 {
  if ((*iter).first == id)
  {
   return (*iter).second;
  }
 }
}
```

But I get errors like:

```
error: missing template arguments before 'iter'
error: expected `;' before 'iter'
error: expected primary-expression before '!=' token
error: 'mRegistryList' was not declared in this scope
error: expected primary-expression before '++' token
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
error: missing template arguments before 'iter'
error: expected `;' before 'iter'
error: expected primary-expression before '!=' token
error: 'mRegistryList' was not declared in this scope
error: expected primary-expression before '++' token
```

I dont quite get what I am doing wrong, but I am rusty a bit for sure....

Comment: formatting issues in your post make answering it difficult.  Looks like something went wrong right around the point where you define your iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that here, you are typedef'ing a type called `iter`:

```
typedef typename std::vector<pair<identifier,registeredObject> >::iterator iter;
```

And then here:

```
iterator iter = mRegistryList.begin()
```

You are trying to define a variable *called* `iter` of type `iterator`, which (from the code you've shown) is not the name of any type that exists.

Answer (score 2):

Check your for loop. What is `iterator iter = ...` supposed to do? You typedef'ed the iterators as `iter` so `iter` becomes the name of the type you want to declare.